# aws-s3 ruby reading object stream to file results in zero byte file

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

even when essentially copying the code from [the docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/AWS/S3/S3Object%3aread), trying to read a S3 object to a local file results in a zero-byte file, nothing gets written.

```
1.9.3-p194 :057 > obj = s3_bucket.objects['/raw/2011-HD/2011-HD001-794.jpg']
 => <AWS::S3::S3Object:mybucket/raw/2011-HD/2011-HD001-794.jpg> 
1.9.3-p194 :058 > obj.exists?
 => true 
1.9.3-p194 :059 > f = File.open('/tmp/4.jpg', 'wb')
 => #<File:/tmp/4.jpg> 
1.9.3-p194 :060 > obj.read do |chunk|
1.9.3-p194 :061 >     f.write chunk
1.9.3-p194 :062?> end
1.9.3-p194 :063 > f.size
 => 0
```

when not using streaming, ie just reading the whole object and writing it, it works fine `f.write obj.read`

**update**

to be clear, this doesn't work either and is more or less verbatim from the docs

```
1.9.3-p194 :044 > File.open('/tmp/4.jpg', 'w') do |f|
1.9.3-p194 :045 >     obj.read do |chunk|
1.9.3-p194 :046 >       f.write chunk
1.9.3-p194 :047?>     end
1.9.3-p194 :048?>   end
1.9.3-p194 :049 > File.open('/tmp/4.jpg').size
 => 0
```

Comment: What happens if you add a `f.close` operation at the end of your writes?

Comment: nothing happens if I add `f.close`

Comment: Worth a shot. I'm not sure about this, but S3 objects may require a `read_body` to get contents.

Comment: `read_body` is not a method on S3Object

Comment: Keep in mind there are some key differences between the docs example and what you've implemented above. Namely `do` loop that is passed the `write` blocks and the file. Presumably you would need this to happen for each chunk to be written. Not having an S3 object available, I can't test to see if this is problem.

Comment: understood, but it makes no difference. I'll update with the alternate "do loop" direct from the docs (actually in ruby that's known as a block)